# Javascript inheritence in jquery way

Tags: javascript, oop, object, handle, object-properties

If I set a function under an object i can use it once only like

```
function handle(selector)
{
    return{
        elem:selector,
        next:function(){
            return (this.nextSibling.nodeType==1) ? this.nextSibling : this.nextSibling.nextSibling;
        }
    }
}
```

here i can say `handle.next()` this will work but if I want to say `handle.next().next().next()` my question is how I can use in this way as jquery does?

Comment: Define a class, and have all your functions return instances of the class.

Comment: the question is how ?

Comment: Just return 'this' from each function.

Comment: More information about fluent interface http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking about your function you can modify it like this to make it work:

```
function handle(selector)
{
    if (typeof selector === 'string') {
        selector = document.querySelector(selector);
    }
    return{
        elem:selector,
        next:function(){
            return handle(selector.nextElementSibling);
        }
    }
}
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xmr4rh5/1/).

UPD: Modified the code to support both elements and string selectors as a parameter.

UPD 2: Came out with an alternative variant. In this case we extend the native html element object and add new *next* method:

```
function handle(selector)
{
    if (typeof selector === 'string') {
        selector = document.querySelector(selector);
    }
    selector.next = function() {
        return handle(selector.nextElementSibling);
    };
    return selector;
}
```

Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4xmr4rh5/2/).

Comment: when i say handle("p").next().next().innerHTML returns undefined

Comment: Fixed: now you can either pass *p* or *document.querySelector('p')* as a parameter.

Comment: still innerHTML is undefined it doesnt work this way @YauheniLeichanok

Comment: Have you tried *handle('p').next().elem.innerHTML*? Basically we have a reference to the current element in *elem* variable.

Comment: handle is supposed to return an element node in this case why i cant reach inner html property directly @YauheniLeichanok

Comment: @nikoss Updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74590/discussion-between-yauheni-leichanok-and-nikoss).